# Intersection of List of List

Tags: c#, .net, nested-lists

I have a list of lists which looks like the following

```
public class FilteredVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

 List<List<FilteredVM>> groupedExpressionResults = new List<List<FilteredVM>>();
```

I would like to Intersect the lists within this list based upon the ID's, whats the best way to tackle this?

Comment: Intersect, meaning you want a final list all of whose items can be found (by ID) in all of the input lists?

Comment: What would you like the result to be? I think I understand you want a `List<FilteredVM>`?

Comment: I would like to end up with a list of ID's that are across the inner lists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an optimized extension method:

```
public static HashSet<T> IntersectAll<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> series, IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer = null)
{
    if (series == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("series");

    HashSet<T> set = null;
    foreach (var values in series)
    {
        if (set == null)
            set = new HashSet<T>(values, equalityComparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
        else
            set.IntersectWith(values);
    }

    return set ?? new HashSet<T>();
}
```

Use this with the following comparer:

```
public class FilteredVMComparer : IEqualityComparer<FilteredVM>
{
    public static readonly FilteredVMComparer Instance = new FilteredVMComparer();

    private FilteredVMComparer()
    {
    }

    public bool Equals(FilteredVM x, FilteredVM y)
    {
        return x.ID == y.ID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(FilteredVM obj)
    {
        return obj.ID;
    }
}
```

Like that:

```
series.IntersectAll(FilteredVMComparer.Instance)
```

You could just write

```
series.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Intersect(b, FilteredVMComparer.Instance))
```

but it 'd be wasteful because it'd have to construct multiple sets.

Answer (score 0):

`Intersect` will work when the type are dead equals, which in your case won't apply because you haven't implemented the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods, which is the best and complete way.

Thus, If you only intended to take `elements` that contains in both lists, than the following solution will suit you right.

Assuming `list1` and `list2` are type `List<FilteredVM>` than, The most simple way, will be doing this:

```
var intersectByIDs = list1.Where(elem => list2.Any(elem2 => elem2.ID == elem.ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are a fan of one-liner solutions you can use this:

```
List<FilteredVM> result = groupedExpressionResults.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Where(xi => y.Select(yi => yi.ID).Contains(xi.ID)).ToList());
```

And if you just want the IDs you can just add `.Select(x => x.ID)`, like this:

```
var ids = groupedExpressionResults.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Where(xi => y.Select(yi => yi.ID).Contains(xi.ID)).ToList()).Select(x => x.ID);
```

[**Working Demo**](https://ideone.com/PvXlaE)